# onclicklistener for button in a list

Tags: java, android, listener

I have a project in android studio with a custom listview. my custom listview contains 2textbox and a switch and imagebutton but i cant find out how to set onclicklistener or another listeners for them in listadapter class

here is my listadapter:

```
public class listadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context_;
    int resource_;
    ArrayList<reminders> objects_;
    boolean bool;
    DBAdapter db;

    public listadapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<reminders> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        context_ = context;
        resource_ = resource;
        objects_ = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context_.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View ViewRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminders_list_layout, parent, false);
        TextView nametxt, addresstxt;
        Switch sw;
        ImageView imgview;
        nametxt = (TextView) ViewRow.findViewById(R.id.remindername);
        addresstxt = (TextView) ViewRow.findViewById(R.id.reminderaddress);
        sw = (Switch) ViewRow.findViewById(R.id.remindersw);
        imgview = (ImageView) ViewRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        nametxt.setText(objects_.get(position).name);
        addresstxt.setText(objects_.get(position).address);
        bool = (objects_.get(position).swbool != 0);
        sw.setChecked(bool);
        imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
                Toast.makeText(context_,position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return ViewRow;
    }
```

but when I'm testing my project and clicking on imageview it gives me forceclose and this error in logcat

```
12-27 20:58:50.343 5658-5658/com.amir_p.yadambendaz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.amir_p.yadambendaz, PID: 5658
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView at com.amir_p.yadambendaz.listadapter$1.onClick(listadapter.java:49)
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
        ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
        ...
}
```

to

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
        ...
}
```

Comment: `parent` is the parent that the `convertView` view will eventually be attached to. `convertView`s are listview rows, & `parent` is the `ListView` that will contain them.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is using tag.
You can use following code.

```
imgview.setTag(new Integer(position);
imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {            
      final int position = (Integer)v.getTag();               
      Toast.makeText(context_,position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
});
```

If you want to save other object in tag, you can use `setTag(int key, Object object)` for saving postion.

For getting Listview, you can use following code.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) v.getParent() //item view 
       .getParent()  //Linear Layout in listview 
       .getParent();//ListView
```

Answer (score 0):

View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
You are writing a listener for imageview and getting an parent from an image will return a row of listview. Here parentRow.getParent() is an row in listView which is a layout and you are casting it to listview.